# weather forecast, probability, task with text

Tags: probability

Every day it rains with probability $ \frac12 $, otherwise we have sunny weather. 
Weather forecast makes mistake with probability $ \frac13 $ (if Weather forecast says it will be sunny, with a probability $ \frac23 $ so be it.

Professor always takes an umbrella if the weather forecast announces rain. If the weather is sunny announced Professor 
take an umbrella with probability $ \frac13 $

(1) Calculate the probability that will announce the forecast rain.

My approach is this: There are two possible announcements, or rain, or sun. 
Therefore, $ \Omega = \{s, r \} $ 
As both events have equal chance of occurrence, I can use probability Classic. 
So the answer is $ \frac12 $ 
I do not know how well, but what could be wrong?

(2) Assuming it rains, calculate the probability that the professor does not have an umbrella. 
I'll think about space events - because I have to find it. I do not really see how to choose, and I try: 
It depends on what they said in the forecast. If predicting rain, then a professor took his umbrella. However, 
if the sun is a professor of predicting the probability of $\frac13 $ took the umbrella.

I mean, we have $\frac23 $ that the forecast was correct and the professor has an umbrella. 
If the forecast is wrong, it $\frac13 $ probability. Then a professor at $ \frac13 $ took an umbrella. 
From my deduction that $ \frac13 \cdot \frac13 + \frac23 \cdot1 $ 
But is it good? If you do not understand what is wrong?

It is very important for me to understand it.

Answer (score -1):

You have the following conditional probabilities: $$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
  {p\left( R \right) = \tfrac{1}{2}}&{{\text{probability of rain}}} \\ 
  {p\left( {r|R} \right) = \tfrac{2}{3}}&{{\text{probability that rain is forecast if rain is coming}}} \\ 
  {p\left( S \right) = \tfrac{1}{2}}&{{\text{probability of sun}}} \\ 
  {p\left( {s|S} \right) = \tfrac{2}{3}}&{{\text{probability that sun is forecast if sun is coming}}} 
\end{array}$$

From these we can derive the probability that sun is forecast when rain is coming: $$p\left( {s|R} \right) = 1 - p\left( {r|R} \right) = \tfrac{1}{3}$$

1. From the rules of probability we have $$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
     {p\left( s \right)}& = &{p\left( {s{\text{ and }}S} \right) + p\left( {s{\text{ and }}R} \right)} \\ 
     {}& = &{p\left( {s|S} \right)p\left( S \right) + p\left( {s|R} \right)p\left( R \right)} \\ 
     {}& = &{\tfrac{2}{3} \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{3} \cdot \tfrac{1}{2}} \\ 
     {}& = &{\tfrac{1}{2}} 
   \end{array}$$
2. The professor never leaves his umbrella home when the forecast is rainy, and leaves it at home with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ if the forecast is sunny. Hence the conditional probability $$p\left( {{\text{professor doesn't take umbrella }}|R} \right)$$ is equal to simply $0\cdot p\left( {r|R} \right) + \frac{2}{3}\cdot p\left( {s|R} \right)$. Plugging in the number we calculated above, this yields a probability of $\frac{2}{9}$.

Comment: From what you know that $ p\left( {r|R} \right) = \frac{2}{3} \text{probability that rain is forecast if rain is coming}  ??$ From text we know only that $p\left( R|r\right) = \frac{2}{3} $

Comment: @xaweyNEW: The statement "weather forecast makes mistake with probability $\frac{1}{3}$" implies that whatever the weather turns out to be, the probability that the bureau forecasts the opposite is $\frac{1}{3}$. In other words $p(s|R) = p(r|S) = \frac{1}{3}$. Even if we interpret the statement as $p(R|r) = \frac{2}{3}$, by Bayes' rule we have $p(r|R) = p(R|r)\frac{p(r)}{p(R)}$. If the probability of forecasted error is equal for both sunny and rainy conditions, it is easy to show that $p(r) = p(R)$, hence $p(r|R) = p(R|r)$ and our choice of interpretation doesn't matter.

Comment: 2nd part, why it is 1/3 it should be 2/9 - coz 1/3 times the forecast is wrong, i.e. P(s/R) = 1/3 but professor doesn't take his umbrella only 2/3 times hence P(u'/R) = 2/3*1/3 = 2/9??

Comment: @codeomnitrix: You're right. I overlooked the fact that the professor sometimes takes his umbrella even if rain isn't forecast. I'll fix the answer.